# How to run a remote Java file from command line instead of locally from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, remote-execution

I have an Eclipse project that contains a file that I would like to be able to run from the command line remotely.

The reason being, it is easier for me to run it for a long period of time if it is running remotely on some server. That way, I can run my program via screen to monitor its progress.

The problem is, all of the things that eclipse takes care of (i.e. package hierarchies, dependencies on certain libraries) is messed up if I try to compile/run this file on its own.

How could I run the file remotely without having to edit the code that already exists?

Comment: Did I understand correctly - you have a program that you are compiling as part of an Eclipse project, and you are looking for a way to separate the program from the project, and then run it on a server rather than your own computer?

Comment: That is the general idea. The problem is, it relies on a jar, and a couple other things and while it would be feasible for me to make a separate copy of the project and move some things around in the code in order to run it remotely, I'd rather find a different solution (if one exists of course).

Comment: You can't just install Eclipse and the entire project on the remote server, and run it there? You can start up the whole environment and project from the command line, like so: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse is actually all set up to export your applications as a runnable jar file, including a manifest pointing to all the necessary libraries which will also be exported. Look under the "Export..." wizard in the Navigator. I've used this to export some quite complex non-RCP applications!

Comment: Once you have exported it as a runnable jar, then you can just run it as `java -jar <jarname>.jar`